# Handling day objects and date in string format

Tags: python, django

Please bear with me as I try my best to explain the problem.

As the title states I am struggling to find a solution for this problem I have whereby days (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc) are objects, and I have dates (DD/MM/YY) in string format.

What I would like to do is for a specific date to be able to identify the corresponding day object.

For example, say if I have a chosen date 25/09/21 - which is a Saturday, and I have an array of day objects

- Mon (id 001)
- Tue (id 002)
- Wed (id 003)
- Thu (id 004)
- Fri (id 005)
- Sat (id 006)
- Sun (id 007)

How can I get it so that the date is able to identify the correct day?

To add to the problem, say again I have a chosen date 25/09/21 - Saturday, and I have an array of Saturday-only day objects

- Sat (id 010)
- Sat (id 017)
- Sat (id 003)

What would I need to do in order for the date to be able to identify the 'correct' Sat object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should answer the first part of your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar 

calendar.day_name[pd.to_datetime("25/09/2021").dayofweek][:3]
# Returns 'Sat'
```

I suggest you to look into [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) modules for more details